# MITライセンスのソフトウェアを使用する場合の著作権表示の意味について？

Tags: mit-license

MITライセンスについて、[wikipediaに記載されている](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)意訳には

> このソフトウェアを誰でも無償で無制限に扱って良い。ただし、著作権表示および本許諾表示を
>   ソフトウェアのすべての複製または重要な部分に記載しなければならない。

と書かれていますが、ここでの「著作権表示」とは、例えば、RMagickを自身のソフトウェアで使用した場合、[RMagickのライセンス](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/2.15.4#license)、

> Copyright © 2002-2009 by Timothy P. Hunter
>   Changes since Nov. 2009 copyright © by Benjamin Thomas and Omer Bar-or

を自身のソフトウェアのどこかに記載する必要があるという意味なのでしょうか？
それとも、自身のソフトウェアに対するライセンス、例えば、私（wakabayasi)が作成したものだとすると、

> Copyright (c) [2016] [wakabayasi]
>   ~MITライセンスの全文~

をソフトウェアのどこかに記載する必要があるという意味なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

前者ですね。

MITライセンス（日本語参考訳）には次の記述があります。

「上記の著作権表示および本許諾表示を、ソフトウェアのすべての複製または重要な部分に記載するものとします。 」

つまり、元になったプログラムの著作権表示をどこかに記載するということです。

参考：
[MIT ライセンス　日本語訳](https://osdn.jp/projects/opensource/wiki/licenses%2FMIT_license)